# Pika: Migration from classic mirrored to quorum queues

Tags: rabbitmq, pika, quorum

I am trying to see if there is a way to migrate existing classical mirrored queues in RabbitMQ to quorum queues. From what I understand the quorum queues have to be declared which would mean that they are created newly. Other than the downtime during the migration process, I trying to see if we can retain existing messages in queues at that point.

Would the migration steps be:

1. delete existing queues (classical mirrored) with name
2. declare quorum queues with the deleted names from above

Is there a way to avoid the deletion and migrate queues along with existing messages.

I am using python's pika module, but even rabbitmqctl commands would be fine if the solution exists. Thanks in advance

Comment: interested if you got anywhere with this? Trying to avoid deletion of messages too

Comment: I've been looking into this and have posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71125253/queue-federation-with-different-queue-types-in-rabbitmq) which may end up providing you with an answer. Another RabbitMQ approach worth considering is to use the Shovel plugin as suggested [here](https://www.swisscom.ch/en/about/career/getit/tech-hub/cloud-ibis-journey-towards-quorum-queues-with-rabbitmq.html)