# Queue federation with different queue types in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, federation, quorum, queue-federation

I want to use [queue federation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federated-queues.html) to migrate messages from an old cluster to a new cluster. Essentially the clusters are the same, in that they have the same exchanges and queues, however in the old cluster the queues are of type `classic` and in the new cluster the queues are of type `quorum`.

I've set up federation between the 2 clusters but it only works if the queues are both of the same type. Is there a way I can override the queue type in the federation-upstream or in the federation policy so I can use queue federation in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue is that the version of RabbitMQ being used only supports `classic -> classic` queue federation.

From [version 3.8.13](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/v3.8.13) `quorum -> quorum` queue federation is supported:

> **Federation Plugin**
>
> *Enhancements*
>
> Quorum queues now can be federated.

From [version 3.8.18](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/v3.8.18) `classic -> quorum` queue federation is supported:

> **Federation Plugin**
>
> *Bug Fixes*
>
> Queue federation will now declare queues
> on the upstream side only if it does not already exist. This makes it
> possible to federate pre-declared queues of different types.
>
> Note that such setups should be considered edge cases. Queue
> federation was never meant to federated queues of different types
> under the same name in different clusters. Such setups could be useful
> in Blue/Green deployment upgrade scenarios but otherwise should be
> avoided.